# Ant Start Java With CMD in foreground

Tags: java, ant, build, cmd

I have a strong feeling Ant is locking up my app, so I want to change the build file to start java through cmd.

I have this command:

```
<target name="run">
    <exec executable="cmd.exe" spawn="true" osfamily="windows">
        <arg line="/c java -cp &quot;build/&quot; com.mycom.prog.Monitor"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

This starts it fine, however, the cmd window is not in foreground (I can only see it in Process Manager), when it needs to be. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will be helpful but here's what I know...

if you start cmd and run cmd.exe in it, it won't show only in the Process Manager...
but if u run it like this: `start cmd.exe` then another cmd window will pop up...

so you can try putting `executable="start cmd.exe"` or something like this in your code and see if it'll work...

Comment: You were close. I just tested running a bat that started a cmd (with start command) and it worked. I'll mark as correct since you're the only one and are pretty close.

Comment: hehe...thnx...:D
I didn't think of the running a bat cuz it was already late here...but good think you came up with it...:D